# Magento Import Extension

Tags: magento

Has anybody used this import extension before? http://www.ayasoftware.com/content/how-import-configurable-products-csv-file-magento-system#attachments It seems to work pretty good, apart from it's not importing images for me, it's really annoying :-(

If anybody has had it working or can help in anyway I'd be really gratefull.

Meant to say using Magento 1.6.1

Comment: Where you putting your images and what are they called, e.g. does you have '/' at front of thems?

Comment: I put the images in /media/import and yeah in my csv they start with /picture1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've now binned that extension, and simply just manuall uploading the products.